# How to rewrite Cypher query, that returns massive amount of nodes when grouping

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need this query to match distinct courses and students. This returns massive amount to me, but when I do return c.name, s.name,count(*), the result is right.

```
  match (t:TeacherEntity{name: 'Teacher2'}) -[:teaches] ->(c:CourseEntity)
         <- [sc:student_attends_course] - (s:StudentEntity)
        with c,s
        match (c) - [:course_assignments] -> (a:AssignmentEntity) 
        optional match (a) <- [subm:student_submission] - (s)
        where subm is null or subm.mark < 4
        return c, s,count(*)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you use Distinct in the original query? is c.name and s.name unique values? Also, not sure what your asking. You say `when I do return c.name, s.name,count(*), the result is right`, which is similar to what you have in the Cypher. Without using DISTINCT, the same items should be returned in the same rows. So not sure what the 'wrong' or 'right' results should look like.

Comment: Can you provide sample data that shows the issue, along with the "wrong" and "right" results?